# Woocommerce add custom button to backend order table

Tags: plugin-development, woocommerce-offtopic

I am currently working on a wordpress/woocommerce project. At the backend, when the user clicks on woocommerce/orders menu, it will display all available order details. In order this table, there are several fields/columns (such as order, ship to, date, total, actions).

Under actions field, there are two buttons (order status and view). I want to add another button under this field. So, is there any code available that can be placed to functions.php to solve this problem.

Thank you.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

@mmm thanks for that code, I didnt know this filter yet. Do you know if it is also possible to add a tooltip that way?

Anyway, I have a different solution to add a new button to this column, and also want to post it:

```
add_action( 'woocommerce_admin_order_actions_end', 'add_content_to_wcactions_column' );
function add_content_to_wcactions_column() {

    // create some tooltip text to show on hover
    $tooltip = __('Some tooltip text here.', 'textdomain');

    // create a button label
    $label = __('Label', 'textdomain');

    echo '<a class="button tips custom-class" href="#" data-tip="'.$tooltip.'">'.$label.'</a>';
}
```

Just replace the tooltip and label text and add your url in the link.

---

I tested the above code on an empty installation and this is what I get:
[image]

Comment: Hi @LWS_Mo, I want to get a button under the "actions" column of the Order table of WooCommerce admin section (which we access by Woocommerce/Orders menu). Unfortunately no button is displayed at the desired location. If u need any other info please tell. thanx.

Comment: @ArnabChatterjee yes, I think I know what you want. I just tested this code in a fresh/empty install, and it is working for me without a problem. I also added a screenshot to the answer.

Comment: thank u for giving ur time.  yes I absolutely want this. but why is it not working in my case ? I placed that code in the functions.php of the child theme. There is no other code in this file. so, where's the problem ??

Comment: Yeah thats strange. I tested this in an empty installation with just WooCommerce and the code I wrote. The code should work in your `functions.php`. Is the code from _mmm_ working for you, because this code also works (I tested his code too), just copy it into `functions.php`. Try to add the code without editing it first, if it is still not working, maybe try to deactivate all other plugins.

Comment: Yes I guess ur code may be workable, but unfortunately this is not working with my site. Can it be happen due to conflictions of other plugins ? or anything else ?

Comment: I guess this is possible, so try to deactivate other plugins. Also try to test the code _mmm_ posted, as this code is also working. I cannot think of anything else in the moment.

Comment: Hi LWS-Mo, the code u gave is working on my parent theme's functions.php, but not child theme's same file.

Answer (score 0):

to add a action in this row, you can try this code :

```
add_filter("woocommerce_admin_order_actions", function ($actions, $the_order) {

    $actions[] = [
        "action" => "actionCode",
        "url" => admin_url("?page=myPage"),
        "name" => "New link",
    ];


    return $actions;

}, 10, 2);
```

Comment: Will I include post_type=shop_order in the  ?page=myPage area ??  thank you

Comment: Hi @mmm, I want to get a button under the "actions" column of the Order table of WooCommerce admin section (which we access by Woocommerce/Orders menu). Unfortunately no button is displayed at the desired location. If u need any other info please tell. thanx.