# How to add a slide toggle to the Woocommerce-Layout__Activity-Panel area in the orders admin page

Tags: functions, woocommerce-offtopic, custom-field

Similar Post, different hook: [Woocommerce add custom button to backend order table](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/291558/woocommerce-add-custom-button-to-backend-order-table)
I'm wanting to add a slider up the top of the Orders page in Woocommerce Admin.
Here's a picture:
[image: Picture of expected location]

Where do I find the code/functions/etc that make this menu?